# Populate Spinner Data

Tags: android, database, cursor, spinner

Is there something wrong with my spinner?? My app didnt crash, but the toast DB could not open appeared. So there MUST be something wrong with my population of spinner.. can anybody help spot the mistake please? thanks!

```
// Open the DB, query all subject codes and refresh the listview
// when app resumes
   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

   ArrayList<String> menu = new ArrayList<String>();
    Spinner SpinMenu = (Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    SpinMenu.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item , menu));

    // Open/create the DB
    try {
        dbopener.createDatabase(); // Create DB if necessary
      dbopener.openDatabase(); // Open the DB

      Cursor menus = dbopener.getFood();
      while (menus.moveToNext()) {
         menu.add(menus.getString(0)); // Get the current subj
                                                  // code, add to list
      }
      menus.close();

      // Update the listview
      ArrayAdapter<String> ad = 
            (ArrayAdapter<String>)SpinMenu.getAdapter();
      ad.notifyDataSetChanged();

     SpinMenu.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Could not open DB", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: oh yeah! and is there any kind souls out there, that is able to help me fill up this chuck of my code with logcat exceptions? those log.d stuff.. I am still quite a newbie to this programming.. hehe! thanks~

Comment: If you really want to use logcat to track the problem then add `e.printStackTrace()` to your `catch` block then post what you see in logcat.

Comment: SpinMenu.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Could not open DB", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

Comment: @Squonk like this?? i tried, but nothing appeared in my logcat??

Comment: 06-07 01:49:52.160: E/Database(285): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.msyd.MenuProject/databases/menu", &handle, 1, NULL) failed